# How to create dynamic links for the dynamic posts in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'll try to explain the problem straight away. I have one HTML form which takes input just like a comment form and it saves the xyz data into a MySQL database using PHP. Now, what I want is to create and display links for those comments on a page.

I mean the comments which have been saved including the user's email and name, should be opened by clicking a link.
I don't want to display all the details on a single page from the database for all the users. There should be a page on which links are shown, when a user click a link, the full post should be displayed in next page.

There is not something which I know about this process. Please help me out.

Comment: Hello D4V1D! I am really a starter in mysql and php programming. All i know is to display the total rows on a single page. That does not create any preview link, simply display the full row.

Comment: You should do some google here. there are lot of link available like http://www.w3programmers.com/crud-with-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

```
// $rows = set of result from your database query
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<a'
       . ' href="my_link_to_display_comment?id='.$row['id'].'">'
       . 'Comment from '.$row['user_name']
       . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: I am sorry Charkan. But i am unable to deploy your code snippet in my system. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I please request you to show your code along with mysql SELECT statement.

Comment: I can't write the query since i don't know your database design

Comment: No worries i found my answer in other post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975223/php-how-to-create-dynamic-urls

Answer (score 0):

First a page to display all the links like the below example -

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE sort_month='11'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {echo

    "".$row['event_name'].""

    ;}
```

and then in event.php(the next page after clicking link)

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "select * from calendar where id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
if ($result){
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$title = $row[12]; 
$content = $row[7];} ?>
<?php echo $title ?>
<?php echo $content ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show details of a single user just do this.
You can make a search box by using a form.

eg. like if I want to display a details of a student, I will search him by using his roll number and run these queries.

```
<?php  //to search student
    require_once './secure.inc.php';
    $status = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $roll_number = $_POST['roll_number']; 
        $query = "select * from students where roll_number=$role_number";
        require_once '../includes/db.inc.php';
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
            $status = 1; 
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      //mysql_fetch_array - both numeric and key index
        }else{
            $status=2;
        }        
    }
?>

//to display
<?php } else if($status==1) { ?>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Roll Number : </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['roll_number']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name : </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender : </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email : </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mobile Number : </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Course : </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['course']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
<?php } ?>
```